# margin of customMediaItem in jsqmessageviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i have a class that extend: JSQLoadingPhotoMediaItem, all works fine expected that in my chat i do not use image for bubble, but i have a background color and radius for textView inside the bubble, if i use the class i obtain this:

[image]

The first one is the textView of the cell with a color background, the second one is a view that i return from class with this code:

```
view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 38))
    view!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.89, green:0.98, blue:0.78, alpha:1)
    view!.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(9)
    view!.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

in a function

```
override func mediaView() -> UIView!
```

How can i give the same right margin to my custom class? or if for example would like to have a view of custom class aligned center?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. To get the same margin for my bubbles I resorted to using the same `JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker` from `JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.h` in my custom media view

```
//apply mask to your view
[JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker applyBubbleImageMaskToMediaView:view isOutgoing:self.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing];
```

You can create a category of `JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker` and extend it however you wish, there was a particular case where I needed a specific color for the border of the bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! i found a solutions, i have a clear background for the main view, and inside another subview with right or left margin based on sender, backgroundColor and corner radius!